# Z-index doesn't work. Popup is hidden under a layer

Tags: html, css, popup, z-index

I am helping to maintain this website http://www.groupme.my/national/

For certain deals with a long list of options, when you click on the "Buy now" button, the options list popup will be partially covered by the deal below. For example, click on the "Buy now" button for this deal "[55% off] Korean Style Handbag...".

Please note that not every deal comes with options. If there is no options, clicking on "Buyw now" will bring you to the shopping cart directly.

I have tried to put in z-index, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Please help to check how we can resolve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code (html/css) which is causing the problem, also what you have tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your concern correctly, the element that fades in has a bottom edge that is behind the item that is beneath, right?

If this is the problem then z-index isn't going to help you because the thing that is fading in is being attached to a div (and it IS going above it) but it is going to be behind the div that sits on the page *after the one that the fading one is being attached to, so, the fading div is going to be behind the next one, no matter what.

The easiest way to deal with this is to draw them in opposite order, so that the divs are moving towards the zTOP as they go up, or to put it another way, set their z-order in reverse order to how they're drawn, so if you have 10 items, the first one will have a zIndex of 10 and the next one 9 and so on.

Comment: I think I kind of understand what you mean... but what do you mean "to draw them in opposite order"?

Comment: if you don't tell divs where to lie they will naturally lie on top of one another as they exist in the page so <div 1> <div 2> <div 3> will be drawn with div 1 at the bottom (back) of the zorder, and div 3 will be on top.  However you can manually specify where to render them, so you can still draw them <div 1> <div 2> <div 3> but set their zIndex to <3> <2> <1> so that the first one in the list is on top. I believe this will solve your problem.

Comment: I think now I understand you, and I have also add in the z-index, in decreasing value. But this doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: I implemented the decreasing value z-index, and put in Akarun's suggestion, now the problem is fixed! Thanks.

Comment: glad it worked. if it was the right answer, you should give it the green checkmark

Answer (score 3):

The `z-index: 0` in `content-wrapper-top` seems the problem ; try to remove it.

**EDIT added after comment :** I found this `z-index` in the generate CSS (line:713):

```
.content-pane-index {
    float: left;
    width: 737px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;<------------------------ HERE
}
```

Comment: Where? Can't find z-index: 0 in content-wrapper-top.

Comment: Yep, I found it when I "Inspect Element" in chrome.

Comment: I can't find it in the html source (view source), nor in the index.css file. There is a .content-pane-index with z-index:0 though?

Comment: See my edit ; perhaps it can help you to find the rigth place.

Comment: Oh yes, that + Dr.Dredel's fix resolves the problem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Dr.Dredel explained the problem well, but if you don't want to do any reorder HTML, I have a workaround, maybe will be little stupid, but I think it should work anyway, **I'll give you idea**, I don't have any code to test any code :)

First, your z-index must not have that huge numbers, like  1000 then 50000! use smaller units like 5 10 15 and so, my code will work if you did that first, I used the largest number that must be on the page.

I'll use jQuery, for Buy Now button, add this code after show pop code:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().css("z-index","999");
```

This code means find parent if buynow `a` tag and parent of the parent of `a` tag and so to div that have `content-pane-index` class name and add `z-index` for max.

you maybe can use this code instead too:

```
$(this).parents(".content-pane-index").css("z-index","999");
```

for close button you need to restore z-index that you added before, so add this code too after closing pop code:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().css("z-index","0");
```

or

```
$(this).parents(".content-pane-index").css("z-index","0");
```

I hope you got an idea at least :)

My code maybe need fixes like add or remove one `.parent()` method, or change selector that used with `.parents()`.

I Love workarounds :P

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show popup remove `z-index` from your popup CSS, for ex. I'm using `z-index: 1000` in the other css

But I'm using other CSS for popup so go in popup CSS & find `z-index` and remove it.